# To show that curves in $P^2(k)$ always intersect for algebraically closed field $k$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, projective-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. How do I show, using Hilbert Nullstellensatz, that any two curves in $P^2(k)$ intersect ? That is, let $f(X,Y,Z),\ g(X,Y,Z)\in k[X,Y,Z]$ be irreducible homogeneous polynomials. Then how to show that the ideal $\langle X,Y,Z \rangle$ is not contained in the ideal $\sqrt{\langle f , g \rangle}$ ?

Comment: It comes from Bezout's theorem....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown :  No I don't want to use Bezout's Theorem . I only want to use Hilbert Nullstellensatz .... this fact is supposed to work as a motivation for working towards Bezout theorem ..

Comment: The variety associated to the ideal $(f,g)$ is composed by the intersection points. If you prove that $(f,g)$ isn't all the ring $k[x,y]$ you can apply Nullstellensatz and conclude

Comment: @Exodd : what you are saying doesn't make any sense ...

Comment: You already used the Hilbert Nullstellensatz when translated the question from geometric language into an algebraic one. Now it's fairly easy to show that $\langle X,Y,Z \rangle$ is not contained in $\sqrt{\langle f , g \rangle}$: if yes, then there is $k\ge 1$ such that $\langle X,Y,Z \rangle^k\subseteq\langle f,g\rangle$, and from this we conclude that the height of $\langle X,Y,Z \rangle^k$ (which equals the height of $\langle X,Y,Z \rangle$, so it's $3$) is less or equal than the height of $\langle f,g\rangle$ which is $\le 2$ by Krull Principal Ideal Theorem, a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

Let's work with Hilbert series. The ring $R=k[X,Y,Z]$ is graded
in the usual way. If $M=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty M_n$ is a finitely
generated $R$-module, its Hilbert series is
$$h_M(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dim_k(M_n) q^n.$$
In particular
$$h_R(q)=\frac{1}{(1-q)^3}.$$

If $I$ is a homogeneous ideal of $R$, the projective Nullstellensatz
states that $I$ has common zeroes unless it contains $R_n$ for
all large enough $n$. In other words $I$ has common zeroes unless
$h_{R/I}(q)$ is a polynomial in $q$.

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ have no common factor, and let $I=\left<f,g\right>$. Then $I$ fits into an exact sequence
$$0\to R\to R\oplus R\to I\to 0.\tag{*}$$
In (*) the surjection is $(u,v)\mapsto uf+vg$ and the injection
is $w\mapsto (wg,-wf)$. It follows that
$$h_I(q)=\frac{q^m+q^n-q^{m+n}}{(1-q)^3}$$
where $m$ and $n$ are the degrees of $f$ and $g$.
Therefore
$$h_{R/I}(q)=\frac{1-q^m-q^n+q^{m+n}}{(1-q)^3}
=\frac{(1-q^m)(1-q^n)}{(1-q)^3}.$$
This is not a polynomial, so by the Nullstellensatz, $f$ and $g$
have a common solution.

Of course, this goes part-way to proving Bezout's theorem.

Comment: This proof looks very high-tech ... there's supposed to be a more elementary proof

Comment: @users It's just counting dimensions....

Comment: @users It is the property of Hilbert series mentioned [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial#Additivity)